# Image uploader provides wrong image

Tags: support, bug

I am trying to add a screenshot to a question of mine.

After I select the picture with the "browse" link, the small preview shows the correct image.

But when I click the "Add picture" button, an entirely unrelated image ends up in the post.

I have tried

- renaming my screenshot file,
- discarding my draft,
- and shift+reloading the browser page.

Still, the issue persists.

Update:

After retrying, now I get a different, but still wrong image. Seems to be something's up with Imgur?

Comment: This is a network-wide issue, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359772/295232